# Strange command prompt behavior of cd

Tags: linux

I've tried this in CentOS 5.6 and Debian 6.02, both guests running under VirtualBox 4.04, and it works in both.

If you type `cd //`, it takes you to root like normal, but the pwd is `//`.  Other than that, everything is like a regular root.  You can traverse the filesystem like normal, but as long as all the paths you enter are relative, the double `//` will remain.  What's going on here?

Comment: Related, but probably not a duplicate: [How linux handles multiple path separators (/home////username///file)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file)

Comment: Not programming related, belongs on superuser.com

Comment: The answer in the link delnan gave gives a pretty good explanation of what's going on.  Unix specifies `//` to have a special, application-specific meaning, so I'm guessing that's why bash preserves the double slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the accepted answer at the link given by delnan:

> A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.

Looks like it's a part of the Single Unix Spec.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11

Answer (score 1):

You've probably using `bash`. At least on my system bash behaves as you've described.

While trying it in `zsh` and `tcsh` pwd was `/` as expected. So I guess it some sort of bash only "problem".

**Note**: if you do `cd ///` than pwd is /. So it looks like a "bug" in bash.

Comment: Yeah, should have mentioned I'm using bash.